# How to add a context processor from a Django app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

Say I'm writing a Django app, and all the templates in the app require a certain variable.

The "classic" way to deal with this, afaik, is to write a context processor and add it to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in the settings.py.

**My question is**, is this the right way to do it, considering that apps are supposed to be "independent" from the actual project using them?

In other words, when deploying that app to a new project, is there any way to avoid the project having to explicitly mess around with its settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that apps can just be added in a project without touching the project's settings is not correct.

If you add an application to a project, **you have to edit the settings**, since you must add it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple.

So why not edit the context processor list?

Comment: Yep. If your trepidation is that you don't want to pass that extra burden on to apps, then I say don't worry about it. I'm already used to the notion of modifying my INSTALLED_APPS and CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings as apps require.

Comment: Are those the only two things that need editing? Because a while ago, I realized the you have to make sure your static_media folder contains the app's static media. In other words, we're talking about 3 different "actions" you have to remember to take when moving the app. I guess I'm just trying to get "more" out of apps than they're meant for.

Comment: Middleware is another common additional setting for apps. In the grand scheme of things editing a handful of lines in urls and settings is minor in terms of the functional gains you get from modular apps.

Answer (score 1):

Context processors are very useful and I wouldn't be too shy in using them, but in some situations it doesn't make sense.

This is a technique I use when I need to include something simple to all views in an app. I cannot attest that this is the 'proper' way to do things, but it works for our team:

I'll declare a global dictionary `template_vars` at the top of the file. Every view would add its own variables to this dictionary and pass it to the template, and it returns `template_vars` in the `render_to_response` shortcut.

It looks something like this:

```
template_vars = {
    'spam': 'eggs',
    }

def gallery(request):
    """
    portfolio gallery
    """

    template_vars['projects'] = Projects.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('portfolio/gallery.html', template_vars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, adding a context processor is the most recommended approach to achieve this.